# Using variables to access a class module field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to use a loop to access some variable information within a class module in Access 2016.

If I am using a DAO instance such as rst!Name, and want to use a variable in a loop I can substitute to this version, rst(variable), where variable = "FirstName" or some other field name to get the same answer.

If I am accessing the field "FirstName" from within a class named "clsPerson" with a line such as clsPerson.FirstName, and want to use a variable for the field name ("FirstName" or others such as "Address", etc. provided by a loop), is there a way to code that in VBA? In DAO I would use clsPerson("FirstName") but that doesn't seem to work.  Is there something that does?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a "common" property like:

```
clsPerson.CommonProperty("FirstName")
```

and in this have a `Select Case` construct to get/set the actual `clsPerson.FirstName`.

But that's about it.

Comment: Thanks Gustav, I kinda thought that might be what I would have to do, but there is always hope for a way that is less verbose :-)